# Better way to call methods of super class

Tags: javascript

```
class A {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  doSomething() {
    //after some calculations...
    return this.value;
  }

  printResult() {
    console.log(this.doSomething());
  }
}

class B extends A {
  printResult() {
    console.log(super.doSomething() * 2); //prints 50
    //or
    console.log(this.doSomething() * 2); //prints 50
  }
}

let b = new B(25);
b.printResult();
```

I can call the inherited method `doSomething()` in `class B` by either using `super` or `this`. Which one is the preferred way of calling the inherited method?

Comment: this and super are different things. super calls parent class method while this calls subclass method (method can be redefined in subclass). super is mostly used when you redefined method but you want to use parent one..

Comment: Thanks! If I also override `doSomething()` in `B` then I get different results from `super` and `this` calls.

Comment: By default use `this` unless you have the same method in child class and wanna call the parent one. So if you later write the child override function there is no need to change your code.

Comment: Keeping in mind that `super.doSomething()` is shorthand for `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).doSomething.call(this)`, decide what it is you're trying to accomplish and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

I would call `this.doSomething()` and let the class or subclass have a chance to intercept it first.

But, if you are in the method `doSomething()`, then call `super.doSomething()` or face an infinite loop.